# How can I solve a system of non-linear equations in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've got a system of equations:

```
for i [1, N]:

        |A_i x (X - B_i)|
y_i = ------------------------
           |A_i|
```

```
the goal: find X such that it minimizes the target function:
sum_{i in [1, N]} (y_i)^2 -> min
```

where `A_i, X, B_i` are `3x1` vectors, `*` is a scalar multiplication, `|v|` is euclidean norm of `v`, and `x` is a cross multiplication.

How can I use Python (scipy.optimize?) to solve this system of equations? I only solved `Ax = b` using `numpy.linalg.solve` previously, so I'm a bit confused.

I'm thinking that I should use [Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html), does it sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I ended up with using the code from this [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Target function
def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='nelder-mead',
               options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})

print(res.x)
```